# Why casting from string to float using parseFloat dosn't give the correct result

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to cast a value from string to decimal but it doesn't give me the correct value this my code :

```
  operation['montant'] =  "12 000,00" ;
    var value = parseFloat((operation['montant']).replace(",", "."));
    alert(value);
```

alert(value) give me only 12

Can someone help me thank you in advance

Comment: The space character terminates the number at that point. Consult the docs: [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) *"...If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -), numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed."*

Comment: ^ which means, remove spaces from the string as well.

Comment: That's right I removed the space and it's work thanx all

Answer (score 2):

```
operation['montant'] =  "12 000,00" ;
    var value = parseFloat((operation['montant']).replace(",", ".").replace(" ", ""));
    alert(value);
```

This will replace spaces with, well, nothing. JS's parse float stops trying to parse something at a white space, so you were only getting 12. Hope this works for you.